# type hint in method for a nested class?

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider a nested class which defines the type of an outer class attribute:

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: list[self.Test2] = []

    class Test2():
        pass
```

Using various type checkers this annotation is invalid. For example, PyRight takes the type of the assigned value, which is the generic list `[]` and not on the type hint `list[self.Test2]`.

`(variable) foo: list`

[image]

---

If I assign a variable at the outermost scope with `bar: list[Test.Test2] = []`, it works correctly:

`(variable) bar: list[Test2]`

[image]

**How do I make `foo` take `list[Test2]` as its type?**

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to lie to the type checker? You want to assign it an `Ellipsis` object and *tell* it that it's a `list[self.Test2]`? What is the point of using a type checker if you're just going to lie to it about the types of variables? `...` is not some magic placeholder, it's an actual Python object like any other.

Comment: ...it's example code, in real code it would be assigned to an empty list, but since pylance doesn't know what's in the list, for loop variables wouldn't have a type hint. regardless, i'll update the question so it uses lists instead

Comment: Is that in a Python *source* (`.py`) or *stub* (`.pyi`) file? Assigning `...` has different meaning in each.

Comment: the `...` has been removed to remove confusion, but it's a `.py`

Comment: Does this also happen when the nested type is accessed via a static reference, e.g. `Test.Test2` or even just `Test`?

Comment: `Test.Test2` works. i can't get away with doing the full static reference since sometimes it's stupidly long..
i tried `type(self).Test2` too but it doesn't work, same for `cls = type(self); foo: list[cls.Test2] = []`

Comment: apparently i can only accept my own answer in a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently assigning it to a variable then using it in the type hint works..?

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        type_hint = self.Test2
        foo: list[type_hint] = []

    class Test2():
        pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that `self` is not a type, and as such `self.Test2` is not either.

Use a *static* reference to the type and it will work.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: list[Test.Test2] = []

    class Test2:
        pass
```

If name length is a concern, use an alias.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo: list[T2] = []

    class Test2:
        pass

T2 = Test.Test2
```